# Why am I being asked to review a suggested edit if I'm not permitted to approve or reject it?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

This evening I logged into codereview.SE. For the first time I saw the yellow-brown box with a number in it next to "review", and I clicked it. The page I landed on presents a suggested edit and the help tells me that I should approve or reject it, improve it, or skip if I'm not sure. But the only button that's showing is "Skip". Why is SE presenting this edit for me to review it if I can't do anything about it?

The page in question is
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24180

I asked on meta.codereview:
[Why am I being asked to review a suggested edit for a locked post?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/why-am-i-being-asked-to-review-suggested-edits-when-i-cant-approve-or-deny-them)

and somebody said that the question was locked. That doesn't make sense either.

Comment: edit was suggested an hour prior to [post being locked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/472/revisions). Edit was able to get through to queue, but it can't be approved because of lock.

Comment: So it's not really a bug, just a "race condition": once an edit is in the edit queue, it can't be removed, even though the post is locked. Is there some kind of DB maintenance that can clear these orphan edits out of the queue?

Comment: probably so, but I am not 100% positive. Locks happen too infrequently for a regular user like me to learn in details how they interact with review queues

Comment: This is a special case where the lock isn't just on a single post, but on the entire question and its answers (i.e. a historical significance lock).  It's probably best to just reject any pending suggested edits when that lock goes into effect; discussing w/ the community team.